# What is reverse routing?

Tags: http, routes, url-routing

Really, it's mentioned everywhere but there is even no wikipedia page named exactly that. Is this just a fancy name for URL redirecting? Does it have another name or definition?

Comment: Where do you see it? That probably means constructing a URL from a route name & parameters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reverse routing is the process of generating the URL that would lead to a route, given a symbolic reference to the route (could be name of the route/view/controller or a reference to the controller, depending on the framework).

(This is "reverse routing" because it's the opposite of normal routing or forward routing, which maps from a URL to a route specifying the view or controller.)

Examples for various frameworks:

- Django has the [url template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-url) and the [urlresolvers.reverse helper method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#reverse)
- flask has [url_for](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for)
- Rails has [link_to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/routing.html)

Comment: Trying to understand the meaning of 'reverse routing'. `Reverse routing is the process of generating the URL that would lead to a route, given a symbolic reference to the route` - what is difference between URl and route ? Can you explain the term 'reverse routing' in simpler way ?

Comment: can you explain a normal routing with an example  and compare it with how it would be used as  reverse routing instead  ?