# What is reverse routing conceppt in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

Please, anyone, explain what is reverse routing with example.
I'm searching this question but still confused about this reverse routing concept.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is reverse routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549805/what-is-reverse-routing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example the following route declaration tells Laravel to execute the action “signUp” in the controller “UsersController” when the request’s URI is ‘signUp’.

`http://mycoolsite.com/signUp`

Route::any('signUp’, 'UsersController@register’);

Traditionally, we may link to the registration page like this:

{{ HTML::link('signUp’, 'Register Now!’) }}

However, this has the unfortunate disadvantage of being dependent on our route declaration. If we change the route declaration to:

`http://mycoolsite.com/signup`

`Route::any('register’, 'UsersController@signUp’);`

Then our link will be wrong. We’ll have to go throughout our entire site and fix our links. Hope we don’t miss one!

Instead, let’s use reverse-routing.

{{ HTML::link_to_action('UsersController@signUp’, 'Register Now!’) }}

Now, the link that we generate will automatically change when we change our routing table. In our first example it’d generate `http://mycoolsite.com/register`. Then, when we change the routes call to match our second example it’ll generate `http://mycoolsite.com/signup`.

In traditional routing you depend on route declaration. In reverse routing on the some action(method, function)

Answer (score 0):

In the route file, we define every route's name and use a complete website that routes names now in the future if we want to change a route URL then easily change it from the routes file. We change only one place and it applies the whole website by route names thus reverse routing makes development fast and flexible.

in Laravel 8, 9

```
 Route::get('users', [UserController::class, 'index'])->name('user.index');
```

now link generate by route name

```
 {{ route('user.index') }}
```